# How is GitHub able to provide service for free?

Tags: github

It boggles my mind that they can offer up to 1GB of free storage for code, etc. for people to use for free and there are so many users. How are they sustainable? How do they make money?

What motivation is behind companies like this?

Comment: By selling their commercial service to companies. 1GB of data storage and a moderate bandwidth is ridiculously cheap nowadays and a single commercial license can cover many thousands of 'free' users while still making a profit for them.

Comment: when you using github for free, your source is open source to everyone. this is how they trade your source for their storage. for the business prospect, their product is very good and convenience, there is many small to medium size company willing to pay for their source control for little amount of money (which is not open source)

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is rather highly opinionated, it's not intended to be for reference nor you should expect what is written below to be accurate. **I could be wrong.**

---

You should do research on [Business models.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_model) You probably use *a lot* of free services every day, even Google and StackOverflow themselves. Very, *very* few services are truly free, while the big majority of services exchange some of your data to earn money.

Now, GitHub offers free repositories very reliably, which is one reason it became very popular. Other users might pay for [premium GitHub plans,](https://github.com/pricing) which can probably make up the difference.

I wouldn't know how much it costs GitHub to run/host something, but as far as one can see, things like bandwidth and storage are extremely cheap. For example [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/) costs $26 per TB, that's very cheap as GitHub allocates approximately 1GB of storage per account.

Now, GitHub has about 745 employees (at the time of writing), and if we assume the average salary is $60k, then that means GitHub spends **3 million dollars per month.** I guess now hosting costs become negligible.

Doing some math right now, it seems like around 300k of team-plan premium users alone can pay up the costs. That means **1.5% of paid users are enough for GitHub to work.**

***Let alone funding from other companies AND also other ways of earning money they use... It's their business :)***